# Convert hexadecimal into short hexadecimal string like "Zx4E5"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working on a bank application where we convert string into hexadecimal string and some time length of hexadecimal string is too long so i said to my senior developer to encode it into short string like as i mention in title and than decode it back to real string.

He said to me its not possible so i want to know is it possible or not?
And if its possible then how ?

He is using following code for encoding and decoding

```
NSString *plainString = @"foo";
```

**Encoding**

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String); // Zm9v
```

**Decoding**

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString); // foo
```

Comment: Consider passing UTF-8 string without base64 encoding. These days everyone is aware how to handle UTF-8.

Comment: If you have limited charset, not a full Unicode, you might investigate for compression with shared dictionary (when dictionary is not passed with data).

Comment: @rizwan-shah Hi. The 'base64' encoded string isn't a hexadecimal string. It contains not a hex chars (hex chars = 0-9/a-f).